# How to enable query logging in Kairosdb?

Tags: kairosdb

I want to see which queries Kairosdb receives from my application and from others. How can I enable query logging?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a simple solution for that, AFAICT it is not available for configuring in kairosDB. The easier is to use a proxy.

Otherwise you may create a KairosDB plugin that adds a logger to the embedded jetty instance.